# How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with 3 columns, wherein each row of Column 3 has list of values in it. As you can see from the following table structure

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,a1,"['Proj1', 'Proj2']"
2,a2,"['Proj3', 'Proj2']"
3,a3,"['Proj4', 'Proj1']"
4,a4,"['Proj3', 'Proj4']"
5,a5,"['Proj5', 'Proj2']"
```

Whenever I try to read this csv, Col3 is getting read as str object and not as list. I tried to alter the dtype of that column to list but got "Attribute Error" as below

```
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv")
df.Col3.dtype = list

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6f9ec76b1b30> in <module>()
----> 1 df.Col3.dtype = list

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __setattr__(self,         name, value)
   1953                     object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   1954             except (AttributeError, TypeError):
-> 1955                 object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   1956 
   1957     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

AttributeError: can't set attribute

It would be really great if you can guide me how to go about it.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your csv (not as an image) , copy paste first few rows of your csv.

Comment: Standard warning: nonscalar values aren't really supported by pandas.  You can use them, as they're sometimes handy in intermediate steps, but working with them is inconvenient, and that's not going to change in the near future.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Copy Pasted values from my csv

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am planning to decompose each row of my dataframe into several rows, such that Col3 holds only one value.

Comment: @user3471409, you want that value to be a list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No the final value will be a String.
PFB Sample Illustration of my requirement
Input Row:1,a1,"['Proj1', 'Proj2']"
Output Rows: 1,a1,"Proj1"
                       1,a1,"Proj2"

Answer (score 102):

You could use the ast lib:

```
from ast import literal_eval


df.Col3 = df.Col3.apply(literal_eval)
print(df.Col3[0][0])
Proj1
```

You can also do it when you create the dataframe from the csv, using `converters`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",converters={"Col3": literal_eval})
```

If you are sure the format is he same for all strings, stripping and splitting will be a lot faster:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",converters={"Col3": lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(", ")})
```

But you will end up with the strings wrapped in quotes

Comment: I'm getting syntax error returned when trying to do this. My string is '[http://whatever.com/extension]'

Comment: Like @5norre 's answer below, the lambda function fails on empty lists returning `['']` when the input is `[]`.

Comment: Literally spent 30 minutes googling for this simple answer.

Comment: Angel..........!

Answer (score 18):

Adding a replace to Cunninghams answer:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",converters={"Col3": lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(", ")})
```

See also [pandas - convert string into list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758646/pandas-convert-string-into-list-of-strings)

Comment: This is a neat solution but it doesn't handle empty strings, the lambda gives `['']` for input `[]`

Comment: To handle possible empty lists too, you can change the lambda to `lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(", ") if x != '[]' else list()`

Answer (score 14):

If you have the option to write the file -

you can use `pd.to_parquet` and `pd.read_parquet` (instead of csv).

It will properly parse this column.

Comment: This is excellent. This saved me from so many other non-elegant ways to save and read data-frames with such columns.

Comment: Good solution but it doesn't work with numpy arrays

Comment: I just want to add that you do not need to dump the file (assuming you have enough memory). You can simply `parquet_bytes = df.to_parquet(); df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(parquet_bytes))`. Great workaround, by the way.

Comment: I tried this, but the resulting dataframe had the column of arrays, not lists.

Answer (score 6):

@Padraic Cunningham's answer will not work if you have to parse lists of strings that do not have quotes. For example, `literal_eval` will successfully parse `"['a', 'b', 'c']"`, but not `"[a, b, c]"`. To load strings like this, use the [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) library.

```
import io 
import pandas as pd

data = '''
A,B,C
"[1, 2, 3]",True,"[a, b, c]"
"[4, 5, 6]",False,"[d, e, f]"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')                                    
df
           A      B          C
0  [1, 2, 3]   True  [a, b, c]
1  [4, 5, 6]  False  [d, e, f]

df['C'].tolist()                                                           
# ['[a, b, c]', '[d, e, f]']
```

```
import yaml
df[['A', 'C']] = df[['A', 'C']].applymap(yaml.safe_load) 

df['C'].tolist()                                                           
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

`yaml` can be installed using `pip install pyyaml`.

Answer (score 5):

I have a different approach for this, which can be used for string representations of other data types, besides just lists.

You can use the json library and apply json.loads() to the desired column. e.g

```
import json
df.my_column = df.my_column.apply(json.loads)
```

For this to work, however, your input strings must be enclosed in double quotations.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for array-like columns in your csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv")
df["Col3"] = df["Col3"].fillna("[]").apply(lambda x: eval(x))
```

Comment: `eval(x)` is a dangerous thing to call unless you are very certain about the trustworthiness of the input. See e.g. https://www.journaldev.com/22504/python-eval-function

Comment: I don't see it as a bad solution, if you are the owner of the csv or know it, then it's working fine