# to_csv() and read_csv() for dataframe containing serialized objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file-io

I have proved that the storing and retrieving of a serialized object from the cell of a pandas dataframe is failing after it is stored and loaded again from csv:

```
a = df['cookie'].iloc[0]
print (type(a))
>> <class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>
```

then

```
df.to_csv('file2.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
b = df2['cookie'].iloc[0]
print(type(b))
>> <class 'str'>
```

in its cell, it only looks like it differs by a square bracket but

```
c = '[' + b + ']'
```

..also does not fix it.

By the way:

```
print(pd.__version__)
>> '0.19.2'
```

and if you need one of those objects for testing you can make one like this:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.facebook.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.cookies
```

From [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) have tried adding `mode='wb'` but that only generated an error message.

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) does not even contain a `mode` option so if it did work not sure how one would get it back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does quoting the string fix the issue?

```
import csv
df.to_csv(‘file2.csv’, csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

I'm not sure if you can get what you need from this but maybe... You could convert the cookie to a dictionary and get the string values from there.

```
url = 'http://www.facebook.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.cookies
c_dict = dict(c)
```

Comment: It gives the following error: `NameError: name 'csv' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `df.to_csv(‘file2.csv’, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`

Comment: Unfortunately am still getting `<class 'str'>` for the type of that object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can store cookies or other non trivial objects as text in normal text files / csv. However, `pickle` will work for you.

```
import pickle

# dump dataframe to a serialized pickle, df.pkl will be its filename
with open('df.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(df, output)

# then you can load it back with
with open('df.pkl', 'rb') as infile:
    df_from_pickle = pickle.load(infile)
```

Comment: I know that will work, thanks.. but somebody really wants it as a csv

Comment: sidenote: I'd be a bit surprised if a cookie jar contained non-textual characters since cookies are transmitted over HTTP (hypertext transfer protocol). I am also struggling with the same issue and trying to avoid pickle for better visibility in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the type or serialization of that column in CSV then [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) may save you:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('file2.csv', converters={'cookie': literal_eval})
```

However, the actual layout of a serialized Python object may be different even in the same column depending on its actual content so probably may have to write a more sophisticated converter function with various branches.

Otherwise, I strongly suggest changing the column type to a known and well-defined format (eg. json) and use its deserialization counterpart:

```
import json

df['cookie'] = df['cookie'].apply(json.dumps)
df.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

based on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034939/3469555
- [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32742976/3469555)