# Read Pandas dataframe from csv file and convert to Python types

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a Pandas dataframe with elements of particular python types, such as arrays and dictionaries, and numpy arrays. I want to read it such that I can immediately work with them (now they are read as a string). How do I do that?

I want functionality similar to [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), but hopefully there is a way to do it without looping over the whole dataframe.

Edit: as requested, a minimal reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

output = pd.DataFrame()
data = {'integer':1, 'list': [1,2,3], 'dictionary':{}, 'np_arrar' = np.array([1,2,3]}
output = output.append({}, ignore_index=True)
    
filename = 'data.csv'
output.to_csv(filename)

input_data = pd.read_csv(filename, ???) # What to do here?
```

Ideally, I want a way where I don't have to input the datatypes manually (not sure if there is such approach).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you tried anything, done any research? Have you looked at the documentation for `pandas.read_csv`, for example?

Comment: @AMC sure, thank you for your correction

Comment: _I tried the suggestion from the comments using the dtype parameter_ Take a look at the `converters` parameter, `dtype` isn't right for this. _I get `TypeError: data type "numpy.ndarray" not understood`._ Alright, and what do you understand from that error? _Ideally, I want a way where I don't have to input the datatypes manually._ How would that work?

Comment: By the way, what does your actual data look like?

Comment: @AMC from the pandas documentation _Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels._ How does that help me?

Comment: Update: It looks like there may not be a straightforward way of doing this for the NumPy arrays (and for other complex objects).

Comment: _from the pandas documentation Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels. How does that help me?_ It means you can tell it to use `ast.literal_eval`, for example, which simplifies things somewhat.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133681/to-csv-and-read-csv-for-dataframe-containing-serialized-objects

Answer (score 1):

For people of the future: for simple data types it is possible to use the `dtype` parameter, like so

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype = {'integer':'int'})
```

However, for objects, this does not work properly. Then you can use the `converters` parameter instead. This is a dictionary of functions to convert a certain column in your data. One can use the function `ast.literal_eval` from `ast`

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(filename, converters= {'integer': ast.literal_eval, 'dictionary': ast.literal_eval, 'list': ast.literal_eval}
```

Be careful though, this does not work with numpy arrays as you will encounter an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because numpy arrays are stored without commas, this is not valid Python Syntax. Instead you can define your own function

```
def string_to_numpyArray(x):
    return np.fromstring(x[1:-1],dtype = float, sep = ' ')
```

and then use this as follows

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(filename, converters= {'integer': ast.literal_eval, 'dictionary': ast.literal_eval, 'list': ast.literal_eval, 'np_list':string_to_numpyArray}
```

Hope this is helpful for someone.

Cheers