# Pandas read csv column values as list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large dataframe with 6 columns, each with a list. When I save the dataframe to csv and read the csv, the lists are converted to strings.

I found one question that was close to mine: [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas).

But the problem is that there is no time to convert every string back to a list. It will take around 4-5 hours to convert all the strings back to lists.

It there an easy way to save my dataframe that consists of lists to a format that is easily accessable in pandas again.

Comment: Is splitting your series of lists into multiple series with scalars an option? Pandas isn't designed to hold lists in series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `pickle`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]})
df.to_pickle(filename)

#Read the pickle file
df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
print(df["Col"])
print(df["Col"][0][0])
```

**Output:**

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
Name: Col, dtype: object
1
```

**[MoreInfo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)**

Comment: Just tried it out with my data and it works perfectly!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use a literal_eval():

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = io.StringIO(u'''
id  list
A1  "[1,2]"
A2  "[3,4]"
A3  "[5,6]"
''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace = True)
```

Input DF:

```
   id   list
0  A1  [1,2]
1  A2  [3,4]
2  A3  [5,6]

# Output is a string
print(type(df.loc[0, 'list']))

# Convert entire column to a list
df.loc[:,'list'] = df.loc[:,'list'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))

# Output is a list
print(type(df.loc[0, 'list']))

####### Convert Column values to List ######
print(df["list"].tolist())
#Output - [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: I indeed used the literal_eval() to parse my strings to lists. But I only wanted to do it once and not every time when I try to access my data (csv file).