# reading data from a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp

So i have a dataset for a NLP problem which contains data in the following format :
code,body,result

2552272216,Does honey changes black hair into white ?,[Greying Hair]

2552210209,"Hello doctor,my mother was diagnosed with depression at the age of 36 due to over thinking about the family problems. Which caused her depression which caused several other mental problems and made her condition worse which resulted into a brain stroke and she passed away. Now my question iscan it happen with me or to my sister also at some point of.",[Depression]

using pd.read_csv i read these lines using ',' as the delimiter but i want the last column to be read as a list and not string .
Please help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import json
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('case_study_lybrate.csv', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=1, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

From the Pandas documentation, it looks like you need to set the `data` parameter.

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

For example:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('case_study_lybrate.csv', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=1, skipinitialspace=True,
                     dtype={'code': str, 'body': str, 'result': list()})
```

Comment: TypeError: the dtype |V0 is not supported for parsing