# How to read data set that have lists

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-science

In the dataset I'm working on,
some columns are containing List of dictionaries

below is an example of a column describes genres of a movie

[image]

The problem is when I use `pd.read_csv()` this column datatype will be string not list which makes data preprocessing harder.

how can i read these columns as list not a string?

Comment: Hi check this out https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval

Comment: please avoid using images of code, post the code here instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter 'converters' to decide special column's type in function 'pd.read_csv'. It's like:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', converters={'Code':str})
```

It will force column 'Code' to be readed as type string.
Maybe it will help you, but I just have a experience about type transform from 'float' to 'str',so I can't guarantee it works.

Comment: actually this transforms to a list of characters so this isn't working, thank you anyway :D