# Convert column of strings to a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of lists in a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
              Ages  MyAge                      Names
0      [3, 10, 15]      7          [Tom, Jack, Sara]
1   [12, 6, 5, 13]      6  [Nora, Betsy, John, Jill]
2  [24, 3, 65, 15]     15   [Tala, Jane, Bill, Mark]
```

For some reason, it is identifying `[3, 10, 15]` for example as one string instead of a list of integers. It is also identifying `[Tom, Jack, Sara]` as one string instead of a list of strings. Is there a way I can convert them into lists of integers and strings in a fast way, or force pandas to read the column in the csv file as a list and not a string.

Comment: How do you read your data file? Please provide a sample snippet to show what you have done so far and to make helping you easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)