# How to save a tricky dataset

Tags: pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a dataset (DataFrame) which contains numbers and lists, when I save it in CSV format and then read it, the list cells are converted to strings.

Before saving : `df.to_csv("data.csv")`  [image]

After reading : `pd.read_csv("data.csv")`  [image]

After reading : `pd.read_csv("data.csv", converters={"C2_ACP": lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(",")})`
[image]

`df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, sep=",")`
[image]

I need to have to retrive the original dataset when I read the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)

Comment: Almost, I updated my question you can see the result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the `sep` argument in `pd.to_csv`??. Maybe the standard `sep=','` enters in conflict with your list separator, that is also a comma

Comment: It put comas everywhere, I updated my post, you can see the result

Comment: Of course it does. What I was suggesting is to use ANOTHER separator, like `df.to_csv("data.csv", sep=";")`, and then  `pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")`

Comment: It gives a string again '[x.xxxxxxxx x.xxxxxx x.xxxxxxxx]'