# Reading lists as lists and strings as strings from a csv file into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I just found out that when storing a dataframe in csv everything gets stored as a string. My problem is now that I have a dataframe where I have a list in the form of : `"['a', 'b', 'c']"`  for some cells in my csvs and some in the form: `'a'`
looking like:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| [a,b,c] | [b,a,c] |
| a | b |

all of the values have a type of str. What I would like to have is the list objects to have a type list and the string objects to have a type string. I know there is this `literal_eval` function to evaluate "list strings" to lists. Unfortunately I think this only works if it is used on columns that only contain strings in the form of `"[]"`and are not mixed with just strings as I get a `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`error when using it on a mixed column.
Does someone know how I could transform the "list-string" objects to strings while keeping the strings as strings?

Another problem I faced was when trying to read in a csv with just ['a','b','c'] in a column, the dataframe came out all mixed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a column of csv as dtype list using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)

Comment: It seems like you might like to think about what you want to do next. I.e. -- why do you want a column with a mixed data type, some strings some lists? What are you planning to do next? Wouldn't it make more sense to have all strings, or all lists? What's the plan here?

Comment: Not in this case because there also the columns have only lists and not lists and strings. The "problem" with literal_eval is that it only works on lists that are strings if that makes sense. I found a solution that I will post. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by just checking if a string contains a list and then transforming it to a list.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df[col1] = df[col1].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x) if "[" in x else x)
```