# How to assign array in a dataframe to a variable

Tags: python, function, pyspark

I need to fetch my array field in dataframe and assign it to a variable for further proceeding further. I am using collect() function, but its not working properly.

**Input dataframe:**

| Department | Language |
| --- | --- |
| [A, B, C] | English |
| [] | Spanish |

**How can i fetch and assign variable like below:**

English = [A,B,C]

Spanish = []

Comment: Fetch array from dataframe? You can use `my_variable = df1.my_column`.

Comment: Please post more details about your code, and the expected output. The example you give at the end is hard to interpret, or translate into code.

Comment: I want to assign an element in my dataframe to a variable. It seems working with collect()[0][0], if array is not null. if Array is null I am getting - tuple index out of range error.

Comment: I want the code to fetch the array element and assign it to a variable as list. Even if the array is empty, I have to get a null list. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: `my_variable = [df1.my_column[i]] if i<len(df1.my_column) else []` that would fetch an element as a list, or return an empty one. Is that the target application?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I came with is just extracting data with `collect` and explicitly assigning it to the predefined variables, like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Department", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("Language", StringType(), True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame([(["A", "B", "C"], "English"), ([], "Spanish")], schema)

English = df.collect()[0]["Department"]
Spanish = df.collect()[1]["Department"]
print(f"English: {English}, Spanish: {Spanish}")

# English: ['A', 'B', 'C'], Spanish: []
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  I completely brain-farted and missed that this was a PySpark question.

The below code might still be helpful if you [convert your PySpark Dataframe to pandas](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/convert-pyspark-dataframe-to-pandas/), which for your situation might not be as ridiculous as it sounds.  If the table is too big to fit in a pandas DataFrame then its too big to store all arrays in a variable. You can probably use [.filter()](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter/) and [.select()](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/select-columns-from-pyspark-dataframe/) to shrink it first.

Old Answer:

---

The best way to approach this really depends on the complexity of your dataframe.  Here are two ways:

```py
# To recreate your dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Department': [['A','B', 'C']],
    'Language': 'English'
})

df.loc[df.Language == 'English']
# Will return all rows where Language is English.  If you only want Department then:

df.loc[df.Language == 'English'].Department
# This will return a list containing your list. If you are always expecting a single match add [0] as in:

df.loc[df.Language == 'English'].Department[0]
#Which will return only your list
# The alternate method below isn't great but might be preferable in some circumstances, also only if you expect a single match from any query.

department_lookup = df[['Language', 'Department']].set_index('Language').to_dict()['Department']

department_lookup['English']
#returns your list

# This will make a dictionary where 'Language' is the key and 'Department' is the value. It is more work to set up and only works for a two-column relationship but you might prefer working with dictionaries depending on the use-case
```

If you're having datatype issues it may deal with how the DataFrame is being loaded rather than how you're accessing it.  Pandas loves to convert lists to strings.

```py
# If I saved and reload the df as so: 
df.to_csv("the_df.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("the_df.csv")

# Then we would see that the dtype has become a string, as in "[A, B, C]" rather than ["A", "B", "C"]

# We can typically correct this by giving pandas a method for converting the incoming string to list.  This is done with the 'converters' argument, which takes a dictionary where trhe keys are column names and the values are functions, as such:

df = pd.read_csv("the_df.csv", converters = {"Department": lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(", "))

# df['Department'] should have a dtype of list
```

Its important to note that the lambda function is only reliable if python has converted a python list into a string in order to store the dataframe. Converting a list string into a list has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I get equivalent approach in pyspark?

Comment: I had a brain fart and missed the PySpark tag and didn't process that you used 'collect()'

Comment: It seems working with collect()[0][0], if array is not null. if Array is null I am getting errored out with- tuple index out of range. Any thoughts to fix this?

Comment: I want the code to fetch the array element and assign it to a variable as list. Even if the array is empty, I have to get a null list.

Comment: It has been a while since I used PySpark so I don't want to offer specific snippets which may not work, but it seems to me like your issue may be best solved by filling null cells with [] before collecting